# sql server cant enter int 00X as 3 digits, but only as 1digit

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using sql server 2008. I want to keep my PK's in the form 001,002 etc. MS SQL is not allowing me to do that. How can i stop it from converting 001 to 1 ?

Comment: use a varchar instead of int and manage you to increment the value yourself

Comment: any method other than varchar ?

Comment: Why do you want to store the PKs as XXX?

Answer (score 1):

Use varchar datatype instead of Int data type.

or

Keep your Pk as int and when use in a query convert it in varchar and then use Left padding 00X on it.

```
Declare @id int
Set @id = 1

Select RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',2) + CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(3)),3)
```

Comment: try it and change it as you required.